# Angular 10 check if a user is null to hide component element

Tags: angular, angular10

I have a component where I want to hide an element if the user is null. Currently it shows if the user exists:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="user | async as _user">
```

Here is the component.ts part:

```
 this.user = this.auth.userSubject.asObservable();
```

I want to do the opposite of:

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="user | async as _user">
```

so that it only shows if the user$ is null

at the top of the logout component is:

```
 userSubject: BehaviorSubject<UserModel>;
```

when they log out:

```
this.userSubject.next(null);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the opposite behavior just negate your `*ngIf`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(user | async)">
```

Quick example: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ick2nu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It is not good practice to negate async expressions, I really cant remember why, but its better to have `<ng-container *ngIf="(user | async) === null">`

Answer (score 0):

<ng-container *ngIf="!user | async"> should probably work for you